# Is it possible to add a rootfs.tar.gz to an existing from scratch Docker container to add shell access after the fact?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

[Here we see](https://medium.com/@kelseyhightower/optimizing-docker-images-for-static-binaries-b5696e26eb07) a minimal Docker container with a Go binary running in a `FROM scratch` parent image.

```
FROM scratch
MAINTAINER Kelsey Hightower <kelsey.hightower@gmail.com>
ADD contributors contributors
ENV PORT 80
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/contributors"]

docker run -d -P kelseyhightower/contributors
```

All this does is run its binary.

But suppose we were given a docker image without the source code and wanted to find out what was in the docker image?

When we look at the alpine dockerfile - we see that it adds a rootfs.tar.gz.

In theory you could just [add this to your docker file](https://ericchiang.github.io/post/containers-from-scratch/) and get access.

```
FROM kelseyhightower/contributors
ADD rootfs.tar.xz /
CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

In practice this doesn't seem to work. (Gives error - `can't find 
 rootfs.tar.xz` even when in same directory as the `Dockerfile`)

My question is: **Is it possible to add a rootfs.tar.gz to an existing from scratch Docker container to add shell access after the fact?**

Comment: Is your extension xz or gz? And when you say the file is in the same directory, was that directory the one you gave at the end of your build command? What is in your .dockerignore file?

Comment: Confirmed xz. No .dockerignore file. The file is in the same directory as the Dockerfile.

Comment: Please include the build command you are running, and compose file if you build with compose.